# Connecting to Amazon RDS PostgreSQL Database from a VB.net Application

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Can you help me to connect to Amazon RDS PostgreSQL Database from a VB.net Application. I already using a Npgsql .net data provider to connect to a local database.I am using the following connection string but getting a error message like

> "Failed to establish a connection to
>   'ec2-dynanet-tomcat-new.cas1xn8fsgaw.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'."

```
conn = New NpgsqlConnection("Host=ec2-dynanet-tomcat-new.cas1xn8fsgaw.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;port=22;Username=xxx;Password=xxxx;Database=esurvey2")
```

[Security Rule Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzCAF.png)

Comment: Where is the VB.net application running? Locally on your computer, or on an EC2 instance? What are the security group rules assigned to the RDS instance?

Comment: Locally on my computer. The security group is given as default with Connection type as EC2 Security Group. Thanks.

Comment: "The security group is given as default with Connection type as EC2 Security Group." is vague and not nearly enough information. Although I'm going to guess that means it currently only allows access from your EC2 instance. You will either need to proxy the RDS connection through the EC2 instance using SSH tunneling, or enable public access on the RDS instance and add your local IP address to the security group.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information. I am new to AWS. I attached the screenshot of the security rules for your reference.